# Exponentiation in logarithmic time

Tags: java

- Input: Real number y and Integer number x
- Output: x^y
- Constraint: Must be done in O(log(y)) time.

Notice that O(log(y)) is O(length-of(y)).

```
public static double expon(double x, int y){
    double result = 1.0;

    double part = x;
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
        if (((y >> i) & 1) == 1){
            result *= part;
        }
        part *= part;
    }   

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is lacking comments that explain the why, ideally every non-trivial math programme should include a brief description of the algoritmh used.

Comment: I think it is better for the code to be self documenting. It's the only way to ensure that comments don't get obsolete when the code gets changed.
Said that, I would definitely add some details in the method Javadoc. It should contain information about what the parameters are expected to be, their accepted values, the produced results and indications on the algorithm used when, as in this case, they are relevant

Comment: Eccellente point @mario in my opinion too the best kind of comments is ----doc. (In this case javadoc.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to make your code more readable by giving a meaningful name to the variables you use. What about changing the signature of your method to

```
public static double exponentiate(double base, int exponent)
```

I think it is worth it, even if you're implementing a simple mathematical function like this one.

I'd also try to make it clear what you're doing with the `((y >> i) & 1) == 1` expression. What about introducing an `isBitSet` variable? I think introducing it (or an equivalent `bool isByteSet(int number, int position)` function) would make your code more readable. I'd also rename `part` to something like `candidateFactor`, which would make it clear that you're computing the factor corresponding to each binary digit and deciding whether to use it or not according to `isBitSet`.

I'd also recommend you to do some validation of your input values. What happens if you get passed a negative value for `exponent`?
You can either make it an exceptional case and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` or handle it knowing that `x^y = 1/(x^(-y))`

Answer (score 0):

Your style seems to be consistent. The code is acceptably clear.